# Display a Notification Once a Week

Tags: android

I am new to notifications in Android and I want the app to display a notification once every Sunday.  I am not sure how to do this when the activity is not running.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should take a look at AlarmManager tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start reading and understanding how alarms works: [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) then you can make the alarm activate the notification on given time.

NOTE: that the alarms won't get saved after reboot so you will need to add a boot complete receiver.